# How to access private repo packages in flutter using ssh?

Tags: git, dart, flutter, bitrise

I have private repo in github, and use it as a packages in my project. in pubspec.yaml i write it like these.

```
dependencies:
  shared_preferences: ^0.4.3
  atomic_app_customer_musteat_id:
    git: git@github.com:organization/my_github_repo_ssh .git
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
```

but then the error is "Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in my github_repo"

I have added ssh in my account, and trying to configuring machine user in github. Then I tried to change it to normal https link, and no errors. but when I tried build on ci/cd in bitrise and get error.

```
pub get failed (69) -- attempting retry 5 in 16 seconds...
Git error. Command: git fetch
fatal: not a git repository
```

But still can't figure it out how to solve this issue.

Comment: I would like to ask how did you create the package? Was it with ```--template=package```, or is it a simple project?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use the `url` line like this:

```
dependencies:
  my_project:
    git:
      url: ssh://git@gitserver/path/my_project.git
```

Comment: Thanks! I missed the ssh part, I think flutter should add this to their documentation.

Comment: More details about things like named commits etc [here](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dependencies#git-packages)

Comment: what in about CI/CD eg github action?

Answer (score 3):

Use this format and you don't need to add ssh in front

```
dependencies:
<module_name>:
  git:
    url: git@github.com:<username>/Project.git
```

Please make sure you have configured the ssh-agent correctly.