# Flutter, how to use a private GitHub repository as a package in pubspec.yaml file?

Tags: flutter, dart, github

Will I have access to the private repository as written below? like for public repo

```
  flutter_component:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/lordyhas/flutter_component
```

or I have to do otherwise

Comment: see if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54565354/how-to-access-private-repo-packages-in-flutter-using-ssh

Comment: thanks for your @Benyamin, I've already seen it, that doesn't answer my question

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it works, like for the public repository, I have already tested it.
You can do it,

```
  flutter_component:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/lordyhas/flutter_component
```

Comment: I don't know why but it doesn't work on Linux

Comment: because you can't access private repo via https, unless you apply your repo credentials (user+password) which is still not a good way if you want to make it more secure. Private repos are meant to be accessed via ssh only